# Why does my Java code return a null value (accessors and mutators)?

Tags: java, null, accessor, mutators

I am trying to get this Accessor/ Mutator combo down and I'm having trouble with it. I'm learning java and this is one thing that I just cannot do.

```
public class Airport extends mainClass {

public String ID;


//Accessor
public String getID() {return this.ID;}


//Mutator
public void setID(String ID){this.ID = "SAN";}

}
```

and that extends the main part shown below.

```
   public class mainClass {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Airport SanDiego = new Airport();
    System.out.println(SanDiego.getID());
}
}
```

When run, the output is "null". Advice about how to get the ID form the main form to not return null, and how to clean up the code would be well appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You never call `setID()`. What are you expecting it to do?

Comment: This is a false setter: `public void setID(String ID){this.ID = "SAN";}` since no matter what String as passed in, it sets ID (which should be renamed `id`) to "SAN". Better: `public void setID(String ID) {this.ID = ID; }`Time to re-review the chapter on setters and getters, because you need to understand how these and how other methods work if you're going to progress.

Answer (score 2):

As cacho says, you are not assigning a value to ID.

To offer a slightly fuller explanation, Java's default constructor is a nullary constructor - this means that it will call the constructor for the superclass, and then it will assign the "blank" value for all of the class's fields (references become null, integers become 0, etc.).

Although cacho's solution will work, you can also define a constructor like this:

```
public class Airport extends mainClass {
//...

//Constructor
public Airport(String ID){this.ID = ID;}
}
```

Additionally, your setID is very strange - it always sets the ID to "SAN". I think you might have wanted something like this instead:

```
public void setID(String ID){this.ID = ID;}
```

And, of course, you can now use the new constructor:

```
Airport SanDiego = new Airport("SAN");
```

Comment: that should work too

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling the method `setID( )` anywhere, that's why.

Try this:

```
public class mainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Airport SanDiego = new Airport();
        SanDiego.setID("this string is not important, since you are setting the value to SAN anyway");
        System.out.println(SanDiego.getID());
    }
}
```

That should work. However, I can't really understand what you are trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the ID property first by either overloading the default constructor with an argument passed in for ID or but calling setID() after you instantiate the object.